# Out of memory crash on iOS

Tags: ios, memory

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b270d48c __exceptionPreprocess + 160 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ab9f5050 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1b28a05ec _CFRaiseMemoryException + 40 (NSException.m:872)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1b289e224 __CFStringHandleOutOfMemory + 32 (CFString.c:1022)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1b27859dc __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple + 2700 (CFString.c:1096)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1b2747d54 __CFStringCheckAndReplace + 328 (CFString.c:6050)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1b278c2f4 -[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 36 (CFObject.m:580)
7   Foundation                      0x1acabd9dc -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 172 (NSAttributedString.m:1196)
8   Foundation                      0x1acabc510 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:attributes:] + 152 (NSAttributedString.m:1017)
9   UIKitCore                       0x1b4ab7394 -[NSAttributedString _ui_synthesizeAttributedSubstringFromRange:usingDefaultAttributes:] + 100 (UILabel.m:181)
10  UIKitCore                       0x1b47719c8 -[UILabel _synthesizedAttributedTextForContent:] + 632 (UILabel.m:1249)
11  UIKitCore                       0x1b4718190 -[UILabel _synthesizedAttributedText] + 124 (UILabel.m:1299)
12  UIKitCore                       0x1b471772c _UIComputedSizeForLabel + 732 (UILabel.m:1957)
13  UIKitCore                       0x1b470ba38 -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 712 (UILabel.m:2208)
14  UIKitCore                       0x1b4717e44 -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 424 (UILabel.m:3803)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1b470d03c -[UILabel intrinsicContentSize] + 276 (UILabel.m:3852)
16  UIKitCore                       0x1b470cd40 -[UIView _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 48 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:2283)
17  UIKitCore                       0x1b46f8658 -[UIView _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 240 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:2231)
18  UIKitCore                       0x1b478474c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateSystemConstraints] + 84 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4623)
19  UIKitCore                       0x1b55bd13c -[UILabel _updateSystemConstraints] + 48 (UILabel.m:2282)
20  UIKitCore                       0x1b4784624 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _sendUpdateConstraintsIfNecessaryForSecondPass:] + 344 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4334)
21  UIKitCore                       0x1b47843e4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 760 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4431)
22  UIKitCore                       0x1b4784300 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededCollectingViews:forSecondPass:] + 532 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4412)
23  CoreAutoLayout                  0x1ce030304 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 76 (NSISEngine.m:1995)
24  UIKitCore                       0x1b47840e0 __100-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:]_block_invoke + 76 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4477)
25  UIKitCore                       0x1b472bc68 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _withUnsatisfiableConstraintsLoggingSuspendedIfEngineDelegateExists:] + 88 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4175)
26  UIKitCore                       0x1b472b958 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 144 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4476)
27  UIKitCore                       0x1b472c3ac -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateConstraintsIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 84 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:663)
28  UIKitCore                       0x1b472b58c -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeededWithViewForVariableChangeNotifications:] + 364 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:4751)
29  UIKitCore                       0x1b472afbc -[UIView _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 296 (UIView.m:13099)
30  LEEAlert                        0x104edd504 -[UIView(LEEAlertExtension) lee_alert_view_layoutSubviews] + 20 (LEEAlert.m:1324)
31  Falo                            0x1031ab478 -[UIView(UgenWidget) ugenLayoutSubviews] + 36 (UgenWidget.m:45)
32  UIKitCore                       0x1b46a5fa4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1932 (UIView.m:18678)
33  QuartzCore                      0x1b3bacc20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 496 (CALayer.mm:10311)
34  QuartzCore                      0x1b3bbf540 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 144 (CALayer.mm:2519)
35  QuartzCore                      0x1b3bd0004 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 456 (CAContextInternal.mm:2714)
36  QuartzCore                      0x1b3bfd3cc CA::Transaction::commit() + 644 (CATransactionInternal.mm:432)
37  QuartzCore                      0x1b3be83a0 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 84 (CATransactionInternal.mm:940)
38  CoreFoundation                  0x1b278d968 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1789)
39  CoreFoundation                  0x1b271d59c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:1902)
40  CoreFoundation                  0x1b2779294 __CFRunLoopRun + 1004 (CFRunLoop.c:2981)
41  CoreFoundation                  0x1b277dda0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
42  GraphicsServices                0x1e9a7b998 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2196)
43  UIKitCore                       0x1b4a12fd8 -[UIApplication _run] + 868 (UIApplication.m:3782)
44  UIKitCore                       0x1b4a12c50 UIApplicationMain + 312 (UIApplication.m:5372)
45  Falo                            0x102337c58 main + 88 (main.m:11)
46  dyld                            0x1cfed3344 start + 1860 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ed159158 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fc5df5f8 pthread_kill + 208 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b95c580c __abort + 124 (abort.c:155)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b95704c4 abort + 136 (abort.c:126)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001fc518f54 abort_message + 128 (:-1)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001fc509a4c demangling_terminate_handler() + 300 (:-1)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab9fa014 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:498)
7   Falo                            0x00000001033e70c0 BLYCPPExceptionTerminate() + 2044
8   Falo                            0x0000000102b28c10 hmdBU_cpp_terminate_handle() + 1008 (HMDBUCrashDetectCPP.mm:114)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001fc518424 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12 (:-1)
10  libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001fc51af90 __cxa_rethrow + 144
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ab9f6674 objc_exception_rethrow + 40 (objc-exception.mm:401)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b277de64 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 780 (CFRunLoop.c:3434)
13  GraphicsServices                0x00000001e9a7b998 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2196)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b4a12fd8 -[UIApplication _run] + 868 (UIApplication.m:3782)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b4a12c50 UIApplicationMain + 312 (UIApplication.m:5372)
16  Falo                            0x0000000102337c58 main + 88 (main.m:11)
17  dyld                            0x00000001cfed3344 start + 1860 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)
```

iOS Out of Memory crash occured on my app,is there anyone have any idea how did it happened?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about memory exception here as you have EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) exception type.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/understanding-the-exception-types-in-a-crash-report#EXCCRASH-SIGABRT :

> Typically, this signal is sent because a function in the process called abort(), such as when an app encounters an uncaught Objective-C or C++ language exception

And for memory exceprion there is EXC_RESOURCE.

Make sure you're working with UILabel and replaceCharactersInRange-like logic without exceptions.

Comment: thx for ur answer! here is what i got for this crash "NSMallocException
Out of memory. We suggest restarting the application. If you have an unsaved document, create a backup copy in Finder, then try to save." may it be a dead loop or sth like that?

Comment: Yep, could be dead loop too. Check recursive invokes